# apps script how to combine mutiple rows' unqiue value into n-dimensional array based on index column's unique value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet likes this, will have dynamic columns and rows each time when update the sheet
[image]
| country| product | type | user|
| -----| ---|--|---|
| JP   | p1 |t1|u1|
| JP   | p1 |t2|u2|
| JP   | p1 |t3|u2|
| JP   | p2 |t2|u3|
| HK   | p3 |t2|u1|
| HK   | p1 |t3|u1|
| KR   | p1 |t2|u1|

I need to put the value into an array , the key should be the unqiue coutry's value, and combine the rest of columns' value (only take unique value), the number of dimensions of  array is based on the number of unique value in "country". in the above example will be 3-dimensional array

I want the outcome array will be like this e.g.
**[[JP,p1/p2,t1/t2/t3,u1/u2/u3],[HK,p1/p3,t2/t3,u1],[KR,p1,t2,u1]]**

for now i only can get the outcome array like this: i am not able to join values  from same column
[[JP,p1,p2,t1,t2,t3,u1,u2,u3],[HK,p1,p3,t2,t3,u1],[KR,p1,t2,u1]]

this is my code, can anyone help what is the issue?

```
function testtogetcombine() {
  var spreadsheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
  
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('outcome');
  var outLastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();
  var counter=1;
  
  var orgtitle=["country","product","type","user"]
 
  var col_geo=[];
  var geo=[];
 
  for (var c=0; c<=orgtitle.length;c++)  {
    for (var j=0;j<=lastColumn-1;j++) {
      if(values[0][j]==orgtitle[c] ){ 
              col_geo.push(j)
        }
    }
  }
  for (var i=1;i<lastRow-1;i++) {
         var duplicate = false;
           for (n in geo){
             if(values[i][col_geo[0]]==geo[n]){
                duplicate = true;
             }
            }
              if(!duplicate) {

               geo.push(values[i][col_geo[0]])

              }

  }

  var result=new Array(geo.length);
  for (var j=0;j<result.length;j++){
        result[j]=[];
        result[j].push(geo[j])

  }
var temp=[];
 for (var j=0;j<result.length;j++){
         
for (var c=0; c<col_geo.length;c++) {
               // temp[c]=[]; 
            
        for (var i=0;i<lastRow;i++){
        
              if (values[i][col_geo[0]] == result[j][0]) { 
                  //  temp[c].push(values[i][col_geo[c]]);
                 var duplicate = false;
           for (n in result[j]){
             if(values[i][col_geo[c]]==result[j][n]){
                duplicate = true;
             }
            }
              if(!duplicate) {
            
               
              result[j].push(values[i][col_geo[c]]);

              }
       
              }
              
          //  if (values[i][col_geo[0]] == "JP"){
             
          //    var duplicate = false;
          //  for (n in temp){
          //    if(values[i][col_geo[c]]==temp[n]){
          //       duplicate = true;
          //    }
          //   }
          //     if(!duplicate) {
                
              
          //      temp.push(values[i][col_geo[c]]);
          //      Logger.log(temp)
          //      temp=[];

          //     }        
      

           
                
           }

        }

       
            
 }  
    Logger.log(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create an array of `[[JP,p1/p2,t1/t2/t3,u1/u2/u3],[HK,p1/p3,t2/t3,u1],[KR,p1,t2,u1]]` from your showing Spreadsheet.
- From your value, I guessed that for example, `p1/p2` and `t1/t2/t3` and so on are the string values.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "test"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const obj = values.reduce((m, [a, ...v]) => m.set(a, m.has(a) ? m.get(a).map((e, i) => e.add(v[i])) : v.map(e => new Set([e]))) , new Map());
  const res = [...obj].map(([a, v]) => [a, ...v.map(e => [...e].sort((x, y) => x > y ? 1 : -1).join("/"))]);

  console.log(res); // [["JP","p1/p2","t1/t2/t3","u1/u2/u3"],["HK","p1/p3","t2/t3","u1"],["KR","p1","t2","u1"]]
}
```

- When this script is run `res` is `[["JP","p1/p2","t1/t2/t3","u1/u2/u3"],["HK","p1/p3","t2/t3","u1"],["KR","p1","t2","u1"]]`.
- If you want to retrieve an array like `[["JP",["p1","p2"],["t1","t2","t3"],["u1","u2","u3"]],["HK",["p1","p3"],["t2","t3"],["u1"]],["KR",["p1"],["t2"],["u1"]]]`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```js
    const res = [...obj].map(([a, v]) => [a, ...v.map(e => [...e].sort((x, y) => x > y ? 1 : -1).join("/"))]);
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    const res = [...obj].map(([a, v]) => [a, ...v.map(e => [...e].sort((x, y) => x > y ? 1 : -1))]);
    ```

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used for your showing Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: That's what I want!! thanks so much Tanaike, your code much more clear and elegant!!!